# Is it possible to have a superposition of two logit models?

Tags: regression, logistic

The problem is following. Suppose, we have a binary logit model with a set of variables. Let's call it the ***old model***. It is estimated over a set of observations and covariates.

Now, we wan to build a ***new model***, which is also binary logit. New model is built over completely different set of observations, and the target variable is a set in a bit different way, similar to the ***old model*** but not the same. However, each observation for the ***new model*** has log-odds calculated according to the ***old model***. And, the *old log-odds* variable serves as one of the covariates for the ***new model***. After estimating the ***new model***, the p-value for *old log-odds* shows statistical significance of the variable

Does it make any sense? What are the shortcomings/advantages of such approach? I do not know the right name for it, but I feel that it is not completely correct. It seems like it is some kind of models superposition, but I cannot find any academical work for similar matters.

Comment: Could you tell us why you do this, what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi! It is actually not me who is doing this. I just spotted it in someone's work, and I cannot simply stand it as a statistician. I just want to find some proofs about such aproach being right or wrong and why. I'm trying to google it, but I do not even know the name for such approach.

Comment: Maybe what they are trying to  do is the same as in this answer  https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/272646/11887  or  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/272121/recalibration-by-regressing-on-intercept-only-with-offset