# Offset option in Proc Logistic (SAS)

Tags: logistic, predictive-models, offset

What difference does it make in estimation of model equation if a variable is specified in offset option in proc logistic?

I know, if I specify a variable in offset option; the variable will be included in the model equation with coefficient as 1. If the variable was already coming as a predictor then will it make any difference to the model equation if that variable is specified in offset option.

Comment: Yes it will alter the coefficient. The overall model should be the same (if I understand what you mean). But why not try it and see? You will not break SAS.

Comment: This is on topic.  Offsets are a statistical issue, not a programming one.

Answer (score 0):

Partially answered in comments:

Yes it will alter the coefficient (1 will be subtracted). The overall model should be the same (if I understand what you mean). But why not try it and see? You will not break SAS. – mdewey

offsets is mostly used with poisson (or negative binomial) regression, to model rates. It is not often used with logistic regression, but you can find examples and discussion here: [Offset in Logistic regression: what are the typical use cases?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/272631/offset-in-logistic-regression-what-are-the-typical-use-cases)